# How to decode URI parameter in Express JS

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

Im trying to send a GET request to my node express route with ajax but i cant figure out how to decode the URI param.

This is whats getting sent to the request GET /exercises/Day%201.

I want to decode it so it'll be something like --> Day 1

Then my query will be something like

```
const program = await Program.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
.populate({
  path: 'exercises',
  match: { dayOfWeek: Day 1 }
})
.exec();
```

JS file

```
$('#dayOfWeek').on('change', function() {
const dayOfWeek = $('#dayOfWeek').val();
const encoded = encodeURI(dayOfWeek);
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: `/exercises/${encoded}`,
  dataType: 'json'
}).done((programs) => {
    console.log(programs);
  });
});
```

routes file

```
router.get('/:dayOfWeek', async (req, res) => {
try {
const dow = req.params.dayOfWeek;
const program = await Program.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
  .populate({
    path: 'exercises',
    match: { dayOfWeek: dow }
  })
  .exec();
//.lean();
  res.send(program);
}
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode URI with decodeURI()

```js
const uri = 'https://google.com/a%20%201';
console.log(uri);
console.log(decodeURI(uri));

// OUTPUT
https://google.com/a%20%201
https://google.com/a  1
```

Comment: Yes! I tried this in my js file it works just as expected. But in my route, its not decoding the uri. I need to get the value from req.body then with that value to query my mongodb database. I read that express decodes the uri automatically. But somehow in my case i dont think its working

Comment: Sorry get the value from req.params